# Parallelization of a scheduled task implemented as @Singleton in a clustered Java EE application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, payara

I am currently developing a Java EE application which will be deployed on a Payara server 4. The payara server works on host 1 and there are also 2 instances (host 1 and host 2) available as a Payara cluster.

The problem which I have is, if we schedule a task in the singleton class, then the task will be executed thrice at the same time. The question is 2-fold.

- Why does this phenomenon happen?
- How can I avoid such multiple execution?

---

The entry point looks like this. (Not the whole.)

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Singleton
public class StartClass {
    public void StartClass() {}
    public void init(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) ServletContext) throws ... { ... }

    @Schedule(hour="*", minute="0", persistent=false)
    public void runJob() {
        MyClass my_class = new MyClass();
        my_class.do_the_job();
    }
}
```

Here the scheduled task which I mentioned above is `my_class.do_the_job()`. This method is just to insert a line into a DB and the source code is very similar to [this tutorial](https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/jdbc/jdbc0002) and has several `System.out.println("DO_THE_JOB")`. The target table has a column which is automatically filled with the inserted timestamp. I also put an information about the host with `System.getenv("HOST")`. And the result is that we insert three rows every hour: 2 rows from host 1 and 1 row from host 2. But the result of `println()` can be found once in the log file.

Notes:

- Usage of JTA is not the point. I would like to understand the behaviour of the application and the cluster.
- Java version is 8
- If there should be another relevant part, let me know.

Comment: Use quartz scheduler, it can work with cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does this phenomenon happen?

Simply because Singleton beans **are not clusterable**. Meaning that each node of the cluster has its own instance of `StartClass`. You may find additional useful information on a similar SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496451/how-singleton-is-javax-ejb-singleton-in-a-clustered-environment).

> How can I avoid such multiple execution?

With your current setup, **you can't**. What you possibly need is a scheduler which supports clustering. A popular option is [quartz-scheduler](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz) which supports clustering.

Answer (score 4):

In the JEE spec there is no way to have a `@Singleton` which is cluster-wide.

One possible option to get around this is to use the Payara-specific clustered singleton with the additional `@Clustered` annotation. It is available starting from Payara 4.182.

Read more about it here [Payara clustered singleton](https://blog.payara.fish/introduction-to-clustered-singleton)